# Migrating a Maven JEE 7 Project to JEE 6

Tags: java, maven, jboss, java-ee-6

There is a requirement for one of our apps built as a Maven JEE 7 project (which typically runs on Jboss AS7) to be able to run on Jboss AS6 and effectively converted to a JEE 6 project. 
I am assuming that a simple change to the maven *javaee-web-api* dependency from version 7 to the older version 6, will do the job but being fairly new to Maven I don't know for sure.

Also not sure if I could use another approach - if there is a specific maven archtype available that can help convert the project. Any guidance on achieving this is appreciated.

Comment: I realize you may not have a choice but JBoss AS6 is very old and, unless you have RedHat support, is no longer supported.  Neither Java SE 6 nor Java SE 7 are still supported by Oracle.  Is there a production system?

Comment: Well this is a client deployment that we need to support and I don't think they plan to upgrade to AS7 anytime soon. I believe if there are a lot of jar dependencies that don't work, that might convince them.